# QA Issue in yocto build while trying to pack symlink in my image

Tags: linux, build, embedded-linux, autotools, yocto

I am trying to build my library using yocto after inheriting autotools. I need to pack ".so" file in the final image as my application dynamically links that library during run-time. But I couldnt find my .so file in the final image, Instead I can see ".so.0" and ".so.0.0.0". So I tried adding below rules in my recipe.

```
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/"
```

Adding this gives me an error.

```
ERROR: QA Issue: non -dev/-dbg/-nativesdk package contains symlink .so:
```

I could understand that ".so" files are symbolic links and I could not pack those in the image as they are intended for dev packages. But Somehow I need ".so" files in the target image. Is there any way out?

NOTE: Modification in application source code to take ".so.0.0.0" is an option but that is least preferred.

Answer (score 6):

The best solution is to have your application link to the versioned library file.

To avoid the QA error when packaging the unversioned `.so`-file, you should add

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "dev-so"
```

to your recipe. That will avoid running the `dev-so` test for package `${PN}`.